# \tableofcontent[currentsection] in article or scrartcl?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a handy way to display only the subsections corresponding to the current section in scrartcl like `\tableofcontent[currentsection]` does in beamer?

Comment: Check out the \newlistof comand fromt the tocloft package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use package `etoc`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname}}{}
\etocsettocdepth{subsection}

\clearpage
\section{Sec1}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{SubSec1}
\subsubsection{SubSubSec}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{SubSec2}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Sec1}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{SubSec1}
\subsubsection{SubSubSec}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{SubSec2}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]